# How to limit fields in a KDB tick subscription request?

Tags: kdb

I have a feed of data coming from KDB via TCP. It's working well, however I'm getting columns coming over the wire that I don't need.  Is it possible to filter the columns on my subscription in the `u.sub` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not out of the box. What you can do is update the `upd` function in `r.q` to select the columns that you actually want, which updates your local table in the realtime database.

You'd also need to initialise the table in `r.q` so that it doesn't get picked up automatically from the tickerplant on `.u.sub`

Comment: this is assuming it's a kdb subscriber. User could also be subscribing from another language!

Comment: @terrylynch I am actually

Comment: @JamesL Hmmm, then you'd have to request/make changes in the tickerplant before it publishes in order to do this. Which might be more effort and risk than just ignoring columns that you don't need

Comment: As the user said, you can't do it out of the box with existing .u.sub